# Is there any platform independent character for tab in java?

Tags: java, string

for platform independent new line I use system.lineSeperator() is there any for tab?

Comment: A tab is the literal character `\t`.

Comment: A tab is the [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/) value x09.